# How to modify the retention time of the classic network endpoint through API

Tags: cloud, alibaba-cloud

I am trying to modify the retention time of the classic network endpoint through APIs provided by the Alibaba Cloud. I downloaded the official Java SDK to access the Alibaba Cloud ApsaraDB Instance. I am following the official documentation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 ModifyInstanceNetExpireTimeRequest request = new ModifyInstanceNetExpireTimeRequest();
 request.setClassicExpiredDays(3);
 request.setConnectionString("<link string>");
 request.setInstanceId("<instance Id>");
 IClientProfile profile
         = DefaultProfile.getProfile("cn-hangzhou", "<Your ak>",
         "<Your sk>");
 IAcsClient client = new DefaultAcsClient(profile);
 try {
     ModifyInstanceNetExpireTimeResponse response
             = client.getAcsResponse(request);
     for (NetInfoItem item:response.getNetInfoItems()) {
         System.out.println(item.getConnectionString());
         System.out.println(item.getPort());
         System.out.println(item.getDBInstanceNetType());
         System.out.println(item.getIPAddress());
         System.out.println(item.getExpiredTime());
     }
 } catch (ServerException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 } catch (ClientException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }}
```

But it throws you are not having sufficient permission to change the retention time. Is it because of RAM (Resource Access Management) Privileges?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it might be. If you are a RAM user you should have a Unrestricted Admin access. Also, have a look at **Alibaba Cloud Security Token Service**

The Alibaba Cloud Security Token Service (STS) provides short-term access permission management for Alibaba Cloud accounts (or RAM users). Through STS, you can issue federated users (who are managed in your local account system) with an access credential that customizes the expiration duration and access permission. Federated users can use STS temporary access credential to directly invoke Alibaba Cloud service API or log on to Alibaba Cloud Management Console to access authenticated resources.

Try this:

1. Create a Token with some validity using STS, there is a java program to do so
2. Use the generated token to make modification in your API

Let me know how that goes :)